# How to chroot the tftp service

Tags: ubuntu, pxe-boot, tftp

I have tftp installed on Ubuntu 10.04 with the below /etc/xinetd.d/tftp file.
I can connect to the tftp server using

```
tftp 10.1.1.54
get pxelinux.0
```

and it retreaves the file with no issue.  When I try:

```
get /pxelinux.0
```

I get a

```
Error Code 2: Access violation
```

This is a problem because the HP PXE boot environment request the pxelinux.0 with the leading /.  I suspect it is trying to use the server root directory as the / root instead of using /tftpboot as the root.  I've looked at the docs, but I can't see a way to chroot tftp so is interprets the leading slash correctly

Thanks in advance.

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a permissions problem, are /tftpboot and pxelinux.0 world readable?

---

**Edit:** Have you tried using the [-s argument](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tftpd) to tftpd to set the directory?

Comment: Yes -- the whole /tftpboot directory is 777. I can upload files and download the pxelinux.0 as long as I don't put in an absolute path.

Comment: The -s argument is what was missing.  Added that and everything started working.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-s` option to tftpd to accomplish what you want.

If I have a directory `/tftpboot` like this:

```
# ls /tftpboot
afile
```

And I run `tftpd` like this:

```
# tftpd -l -s /tftpboot
```

Then this:

```
tftp> get afile
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
tftp> get /afile
```

You would modify the `server_args` line of your configuration file:

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = -s /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```